# How to convert a string mixed with infix and prefix sub-expressions to all prefix sub-expressions?

Tags: python, regex, string, parsing, stack

Consider I have a string formula which is written in this format: "func(a+b,c)", where func is a custom function, this string contains both infix(i.e. the +) and prefix(i.e. the func) representations, I'd like to convert it to a string with all prefix representations, "func(+(a,b), c)", how can I do that?

Another example is "func1(a*(b+c),d)-func2(e,f)" to "-(func1(*(a, +(b,c)), d), func2(e,f))"

More background:
I want to build a parser, where the user would input the expressions in string format just as described above, normally a custom function would be written as a prefix expression, i.e. "func(a,b)", but due to the common convention, people would still write the +-*/ in an infix expression, i.e. "a+b".

If an expression is given in all infix format, I can easily convert it to a tree object I predefined, but if an expression is mixed with both prefix and infix formats, I have no idea how to convert it to a tree object, thus asking how to convert the string to all infix formats.

I have no experience with parsers, appreciate any initial guidance.

Comment: Time to do some research on writing parsers.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited my question with more background

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the language you are parsing is that similar to Python, you can just use the Python parser as provided by the built-in [ast](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) module, and implement a visitor over the nodes that interest you, in order to build up the prefix expression.  For example, you could try this:

```py
import ast

def printc(*args): print(*args, end='')

class PrefixPrinter(ast.NodeVisitor):
    def visit_BinOp(self, node):
        if type(node.op) == ast.Add:
            printc("+")
        if type(node.op) == ast.Sub:
            printc("-")
        if type(node.op) == ast.Mult:
            printc("*")
        if type(node.op) == ast.Div:
            printc("/")
        printc("(")
        self.visit(node.left)
        printc(",")
        self.visit(node.right)
        printc(")")

    def visit_Call(self, node):
        self.visit(node.func)
        printc("(")
        for index, arg in enumerate(node.args):
            self.visit(arg)
            if index < len(node.args) - 1:
                printc(", ")
        printc(")")

    def visit_Name(self, node):
        printc(node.id)

first_example = "func(a+b,c)"
second_example = "func1(a*(b+c),d)-func2(e,f)"
printc(f"{first_example=} converts to ")
PrefixPrinter().visit(ast.parse(first_example))
print()
printc(f"{second_example=} converts to ")
PrefixPrinter().visit(ast.parse(second_example))
print()
```

Execution:

```bash
$ python3 to_prefix.py 
first_example='func(a+b,c)' converts to func(+(a,b), c)
second_example='func1(a*(b+c),d)-func2(e,f)' converts to -(func1(*(a,+(b,c)), d),func2(e, f))
```